# How to make italic rounded style system text in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

It seems SwiftUI font italic modifier does not have an effect on text with the system font style.

Having a `.font(.system())` makes `.italic()` not changing the font style any more. is there a workaround for this behavior?

`.rounded` design should still be there after applying an italic modifier.

```
        Text(sampleSentence)
            .italic() // <--- Does not work
            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SF Pro Rounded, the font that gets used when you specify `.rounded`, doesn't support italics. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/#sf-pro-rounded-and-sf-compact-rounded):

> SF Pro Rounded and SF Compact Rounded support:
>
> - Uprights in nine weights — from Ultralight to Black

It doesn't say italics. Meanwhile, [for SF Pro](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/#sf-pro-and-sf-compact):

> SF Pro and SF Compact support:
>
> - Nine weights — from Ultralight to Black — in **both uprights and italics**